# Selenium Python how to get text(html source) from <div>

Tags: python, html, selenium, tags

I'm trying to get text `$27.5` inside tag `<div>`, I located the element by id and the element is called "price".

The snippet of html is as follows:

```
<div id="PPP,BOSSST,NYCPAS,2015-04-26T01:00:00-04:00,2015-04-26T05:20:00-04:00,_price" class="price inlineBlock strong mediumText">$27.50</div>
```

Here is what I've tried

```
price.text
price.get_attribute('value')
```

Both of the above doesn't work.

**Update:**
Thanks for everyone that tries to help.
I combined your answers together and got the solution:)

```
    price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='price inlineBlock strong mediumText']")
    price_content = price.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    print price_content.strip()
```

Comment: price.text should be the way to go. probably the selector for *price* is wrong..Can you provide the code which finds the price object? And, specify the error

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. Yeah, I think price.text should work. Here is my code to get the element         price = fltright.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[id$='_price']"). There is no error, that's why I got even more confused. I tried to print out price.text, but nothing happens.

Comment: Your id in the html snippet is "_priceMobile" and in your code it is "_price". Is that correct?

Comment: [Why is it not possible to interact with hidden elements?](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_Why_is_it_not_possible_to_interact_with_hidden_elements?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use a regular expression or Beautiful Soup to find the contents of the element in HTML:

```
re.search(r'<div.*?>(*.?)</div>', price.get_attribute('innerHTML')).group(1)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get it. Can you explain a little bit, please? Thanks.

Comment: Well is it working, first of all? This is basically a code to search the HTML for the contents between the tags.

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work for me. I tried this code, there is an error while compiling:    raise error, v # invalid expression

Comment: Did you import `re` and do you have a `price` element?

Comment: Yes, I did. And I've already correctly located the element I want.

Comment: Partly, I've already updated the solution in my post~ I marked it as solution because it's the most helpful in finding my solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the css selector to

```
div[id$='_price']
```

Complete code

```
 price = fltright.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id$='_price']")
 price.text
```

Comment: I'm so sorry. I copied the wrong html snippet. I've already updated my question. Can you take a look, please? Thank you!

Comment: The edit still should work. Have you tried changing the selector? And, is that hidden?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, it's different, it doesn't have the tag <strong> now. I think I correctly locate the element I need, cause when I try to print the id for "price", I got what I was looking for. But I can't get the text:(

Answer (score 0):

You element is hidden, last I worked with `Selenium` you were not able to get text of hidden elements. That said, you can always execute javascript, I dont usually write in python, but it should be something like:

```
def val = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('locator').innerHTML")
```

Comment: I do not think using `getElementById` is a very good idea in this case

Comment: I was just suggesting, that the way to achieve what is asked is to execute javascript.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I copied the wrong html snippet. I've already updated my question. Can you take a look, please? Thank you!

Comment: `driver.get_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='price inlineBlock strong mediumText']").text` ?

Comment: @Erki M. I think you mean,  find_element_by_xpath. Unfortunately, I got the same result. Nothing happens, When I try to print, no error, no printing.

Comment: does the find element return you the element you need? maybe there are more than one elements matching the xpath? If so, refine that xpath. if the xpath does not result in a webElement, then get the locator right.

Comment: @Erki M. Yes. I think I correctly locate the element I need, cause when I try to print the id for "price", I got what I was looking for. But I can't get the text:(

Answer (score 0):

I tried your edited solution, but they only get 1 `div` having `class`. So, I tried these below to print a List of `div` having the same `class`.

Changing `element` to `elements` will output a List:

```
price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "price inlineBlock strong mediumText"]')
```

Use `for ... in range ()` to print a List:

```
num = len (price)
for i in range (num):
  print (price[i].text)
```

Answer (score -2):

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='workQueueTaskListForm']/div[1]/p").text

Comment: This question was asked and answer accepted 3 years ago.